# Use printf to print character string in hexadecimal format, distorted results

Tags: c, printf

I want to print a character string in hexadecimal format on machine A. Something like:

```
ori_mesg = gen_rdm_bytestream (1400, seed)
sendto(machine B, ori_mesg, len(mesg))
```

On machine B

```
recvfrom(machine A, mesg)

mesg_check = gen_rdm_bytestream (1400, seed)

for(i=0;i<20;i++){
    printf("%02x ", *(mesg+i)& 0xFF);
}
printf("\n");
for(i=0; i<20; i++){
    printf("%02x ", *(mesg_check+i));
}
printf("\n");
```

`seed` varies among 1, 2, 3, ...

The bytes generation funcion is:

```
u_char *gen_rdm_bytestream (size_t num_bytes, unsigned int seed)
{
    u_char *stream = malloc (num_bytes+4);
    size_t i;

    u_int16_t seq = seed;
    seq = htons(seq);
    u_int16_t tail = num_bytes;
    tail = htons(tail);
    memcpy(stream, &seq, sizeof(seq));
    srand(seed);
    for (i = 3; i < num_bytes+2; i++){
        stream[i] = rand ();
    }
    memcpy(stream+num_bytes+2, &tail, sizeof(tail));

    return stream;
}
```

But I got results from printf like:

```
00 01 00 67 c6 69 73 51 ff 4a ec 29 cd ba ab f2 fb e3 46 7c
00 01 00 67 ffffffc6 69 73 51 ffffffff 4a ffffffec 29 ffffffcd ffffffba ffffffab fffffff2 fffffffb ffffffe3 46 7c
```

or

```
00 02 88 fa 7f 44 4f d5 d2 00 2d 29 4b 96 c3 4d c5 7d 29 7e
00 02 00 fffffffa 7f 44 4f ffffffd5 ffffffd2 00 2d 29 4b ffffff96 ffffffc3 4d ffffffc5 7d 29 7e
```

Why are there so many `fffff` for `mesg_check`?

Are there any potential reasons for this phenomenon?

Comment: What do `mesg` and `mesg_check` look like?

Comment: would mesg be a char* or char[] by any chance?

Comment: what is `mesg` and `mesg_check`? Maybe pointer arithmetic problems?

Comment: Try to put a `space` in the printf specifier.  Ie, "%2.2x "  You are getting many number put together and negatives are being sign extended.

Comment: `for (i = 3; i < num_bytes+2; i++){` <- you're leaving `stream[2]` unwritten-to.

Comment: `%2.2x` ??? what does this mean?

Comment: @misteryes `%2.2x` means to make the max/min of the hex string 2 characters.  So it will only ever print two digits.  You seem to know it is a single byte, so no matter how the compiler converts things, you will end up with only two ASCII hex characters.  After your edit, it still looks like a conversion issue.  You can also use `*(mesg_check+i) & 0xff`, if that is the way you want to go.

Comment: You accepted an answer, but you still haven't shown us how `mesg` and `mesg_check` are defined -- not how you initialize them, but what their declarations look like. Showing us that could be helpful to future readers of this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does printf not print out just one byte when printing hex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555791/why-does-printf-not-print-out-just-one-byte-when-printing-hex)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's a small program that illustrates the problem I *think* you might be having:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    char arr[] = { 0, 16, 127, 128, 255 };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof arr; i ++) {
        printf(" %2x", arr[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

On my system (on which plain `char` is signed), I get this output:

```
  0 10 7f ffffff80 ffffffff
```

The value `255`, when stored in a (signed) `char`, is stored as `-1`.  In the `printf` call, it's promoted to (signed) `int` -- but the `"%2x"` format tells `printf` to treat it as an `unsigned int`, so it displays `fffffffff`.

Make sure that your `mesg` and `mesg_check` arrays are defined as arrays of `unsigned char`, not plain `char`.

**UPDATE:** Rereading this answer more than a year later, I realize it's not quite correct. Here's a program that works correctly on my system, and will almost certainly work on any reasonable system:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
    unsigned char arr[] = { 0, 16, 127, 128, 255 };
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof arr; i ++) {
        printf(" %02x", arr[i]);
    }
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
 00 10 7f 80 ff
```

An argument of type `unsigned char` is promoted to (signed) `int` (assuming that `int` can hold all values of type `unsigned char`, i.e., `INT_MAX >= UCHAR_MAX`, which is the case on practically all systems). So the argument `arr[i]` is promoted to `int`, while the `" %02x"` format requires an argument of type `unsigned int`.

The C standard strongly implies, but doesn't *quite* state directly, that arguments of corresponding signed and unsigned types are interchangeable as long as they're within the range of both types -- which is the case here.

To be *completely* correct, you need to ensure that the argument is actually of type `unsigned int`:

```
printf("%02x", (unsigned)arr[i]);
```

Comment: Can't he just use a *width* and *precision* like "%2.2x" and then it doesn't matter if it is signed or not?  I guess it is more efficient to change the *sign*.

Comment: ah, `mesg` is from `recvfrom()`, which is of type `void*`, so how can I change the bytes to unsigned char?

Comment: +1 thats indeed what's happening, but the easiest way out is to just mask off all the rubbish, like `printf(" %2x", arr[i] & 0xFF);`

Comment: I tried something like  `printf("%2x", *((u_char*)(mesg+i)));`it is still wrong, here you `arr[i]` is `mesg` or `mesg_check` ?

Comment: I tried `for(i=0;i<20;i++){printf("%2.2x", *(mesg+i)& 0xFF); , still the results are like: 
`00010067c6697351ff4aec29cdbaabf2fbe3467c`  and 
`00010067ffffffc6697351ffffffff4affffffec29ffffffcdffffffbaffffffabfffffff2fffffffbffffffe3467c`

Comment: @misteryes: The real question is, how are `mesg` and `mesg_check` defined? Presumably you defined them yourself (in code you haven't yet shown us). If you're dealing with raw byte data, `unsigned char` is a better choice than plain `char` (for this and other reasons); plain `char` is for *character* data. You can pass an `unsigned char*` as the 2nd argument to `recvfrom()`. And if you're dumping data in hex, then `"%02x"` typically makes more sense; it prints values less than `0x10` with a leading 0.

Comment: @misteryes: At least for testing, please add spaces between the elements you're printing; otherwise it's impossible to tell where one ends and the next begins, since you're getting different lengths of output.

Comment: @misteryes: You still haven't shown us how you defined `mesg` and `mesg_check`. Are they arrays of `char`? If so, what happens when you change them to arrays of `unsigned char`?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, always print the string in hexadecimal format as:

```
for(i=0; till string length; i++)
    printf("%02X", (unsigned char)str[i]);
```

You will get an error when you try to print the whole string in one go and when printing the hexadecimal string character by character which is using *'unsigned char'* if the string is in format other than *'unsigned char'*.

Comment: That's not code, that's pseudo code. Please provide a complete example.