# Format specifier for unsigned char

Tags: c

Say I want to print `unsigned char`:

```
unsigned char x = 12;
```

which is correct. This:

```
printf("%d",x);
```

or this:

```
printf("%u",x);
```

?

The thing is elsewhere on SO I encountered such discussion:

*-Even with ch changed to unsigned char, the behavior of the code is not defined by the C standard. This is because the unsigned char is promoted to an int (in normal C implementations), so an int is passed to printf for the specifier %u. However, %u expects an unsigned int, so the types do not match, and the C standard does not define the behavior*

*-Your comment is incorrect. The C11 standard states that the conversion specifier must be of the same type as the function argument itself, not the promoted type. This point is also specifically addressed in the description of the hh length modifier: "the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions, but its value shall be converted to signed char or unsigned char before printing"*

So which is correct? Any reliable source saying on this matter? (In that sense we should also print `unsigned short` int with %d because it can be promoted to `int`?).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct one is*:

```
printf("%d",x);
```

This is because of *default argument promotions* as `printf()` is variadic function. This means that `unsigned char` value is always promoted to `int`.

From N1570 (C11 draft) `6.5.2.2/6` *Function calls* (emphasis mine going forward):

> If the expression that denotes the called function has a type that
>   does not include a prototype, the **integer promotions** are performed on
>   each argument, and arguments that have type `float` are promoted to
>   `double`. These are called the *default argument promotions*.

and `6.5.2.2/7` subclause tells:

> The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes
>   argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter.
>   The **default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments**.

These integer promotions are defined in `6.3.1.1/2` *Boolean, characters, and integers*:

> If an `int` **can represent all values of the original type** (as restricted
>   by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an `int`;
>   otherwise, it is converted to an `unsigned int`. These are called the
>   *integer promotions*<sup>.58)</sup> All other types are unchanged by the integer
>   promotions.

This quote answers your second question of `unsigned short` (see comment below).

---

<sup>* with exception to more than 8 bits `unsigned char` (e.g. it might occupy 16 bit), see @chux's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27552302/586873).</sup>

Answer (score 10):

Correct format specifier  for `unsigned char x = 12` depends on a number of things:

If `INT_MAX >= UCHAR_MAX`, which is often the case, use `"%d"`.  In this case an `unsigned char` is promoted to `int`.

```
printf("%d",x);
```

Otherwise use `"%u"` (or `"%x"`, `"%o"`).  In this case an `unsigned char` is promoted to `unsigned`.

```
printf("%u",x);
```

Up-to-date compilers support the `"hh"` length modifier, which compensates for this ambiguity.  Should`x` get promoted to `int` or `unsigned` due to the standard promotions of variadic parameters, `printf()` converts it to `unsigned char` before printing.

```
printf("%hhu",x);
```

If dealing with an old compiler without `"hh"` or seeking highly portable code, use explicit casting

```
printf("%u", (unsigned) x);
```

---

The same issue/answer applies to `unsigned short`, expect `INT_MAX >= USHRT_MAX` and use `"h"` instead of `"hh"`.

Comment: I have just came to the same conclusion. Using `d` with unsigned char can cause ub, please see discussion (see my newest comment): http://stackoverflow.com/a/36350763/4082723 I would like to hear you opinion.

Comment: @2501 When printing `char`, `unsigned char`, `signed char` ... `int`, `unsigned`, consider what is _defined_  and start with 2 specifications:  ( 1) Any lower rank integer than `int/unsigned` will get promoted to  `int/unsigned`.  2) `...` argument: "... one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types" (C11 §6.5.2.2). So when considering if `”hhd”, “hhu”, … “d”, “u”`, is _defined_ with `printf()`, **the original type is irrelevant**, only the promoted type and the value is of concern.

Comment: @2501 ... Then we only need to consider these cases to see if behavior is _defined_:   A) Specifiers “d”, “hd”, “hhd” with an `int` argument (or `unsigned` argument in range of `int`) and the value is in range of `int`, `short`, `signed char`, B) “…u”, “…o”, “…x”, “…X” with an `unsigned` argument (or `int` argument in range of `unsigned`), of any value.  I _think_ the case like A) with a value outside the range is implementation dependent.

Comment: Would you add information on "seeking highly portable code"?

Answer (score 2):

For cross platform development, I typically bypass the promoting issue by using `inttypes.h`

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/inttypes.h.html

This header (which is in the C99 standard) defines all the printf types for the basic types. So if you want an uint8_t (a syntax which I highly suggest using instead of unsigned char) I would use

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdint.h>
uint8_t x;
printf("%" PRIu8 "\n",x);
```

Comment: For cross platform development, the range of `unsigned char` may not match the range of `uint8_t`. A compliant C11 compiler does not have to implement `uint8_t` - "These types are optional." –

Comment: @chux `uint8_t` would be used when it is desirable to cause a compilation error instead of faulty behaviour when a platform does not have 8-bit addressable units.

Answer (score 2):

Both, `unsigned char` and `unsigned short`, can always safely be printed with `%u`. Default argument promotions convert them either to `int` or to `unsigned int`. If they are promoted to the latter, everything is fine (the format specifier and the type passed match), otherwise C11 (n1570) 6.5.2.2 p6, first bullet, applies:

> - one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types;

The standard is quite clear that default argument promotions apply to the variadic arguments of `printf`, e.g. it's mentioned again for the (mostly useless) `h` and `hh` length modifiers (ibid. 7.21.6.1 p7, emph. mine):

> `hh` -- Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `signed char` or `unsigned char` argument (*the argument will have been promoted according to the integer promotions*, but its value shall be converted to `signed char` or `unsigned char` before printing); [...]

Comment: yes `h` and `hh` are *mostly useless* for `printf()`, but they were mostly added for symmetry because they are not useless for `scanf()`.

Comment: I think that explains it. I was wondering about that and came across this.