# C - unsigned char * to char

Tags: c, embedded, rtos

I'm not an expert in C and have some understanding problems regarding char conversion. I've written some code which is working just fine, but I don't like it that much...

I was hoping one you guys can come up with an better, more optimized version. Also I'm getting an output like this: NETAPP EVENT] IP Acquired: 192.168.0__.111 (_ = space). How can I get rid of the spaces, when there is only one digit?

Thanks

Embedded working coder to print an PIv4 address to the serial console:

```
...


 //Print IP in UART
       sl_NetCfgGet(SL_IPV4_STA_P2P_CL_GET_INFO, &dhcpIsOn, &len,(unsigned char *)&ipV4);

       const unsigned char ip_c_3 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 3);
       char ip_3[3];
       sprintf(ip_3,"%ld", (int)ip_c_3);

       const unsigned char ip_c_2 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 2);
       char ip_2[3];
       sprintf(ip_2,"%ld", (int)ip_c_2);

       const unsigned char ip_c_1 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 1);
       char ip_1[3];
       sprintf(ip_1,"%ld", (int)ip_c_1);

       const unsigned char ip_c_0 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 0);
       char ip_0[3];
       sprintf(ip_0,"%ld", (int)ip_c_0);

       UART_write(uart,"[NETAPP EVENT] IP Acquired: ",sizeof("[NETAPP EVENT] IP Acquired: "));
       UART_write(uart,ip_3, sizeof(ip_3));
       UART_write(uart,".",1);
       UART_write(uart,ip_2,sizeof(ip_2));
       UART_write(uart,".",1);
       UART_write(uart,ip_1,sizeof(ip_1));
       UART_write(uart,".",1);
       UART_write(uart,ip_0,sizeof(ip_0));
       UART_write(uart,"\n",2);
...
```

UART_write:

```
/*!
 *  @brief  Function that writes data to a UART
 *
 *  This function initiates an operation to write data to a UART controller.
 *
 *  In UART_MODE_BLOCKING, UART_write will block task execution until all
 *  the data in buffer has been written.
 *
 *  In UART_MODE_CALLBACK, UART_write does not block task execution an calls a
 *  callback function specified by writeCallback.
 *
 *  @param  handle      A UART_Handle
 *
 *  @param  buffer      A pointer to buffer containing data to be written
 *
 *  @param  size        The number of bytes in buffer that should be written
 *                      onto the UART.
 *
 *  @return Returns the number of bytes that have been written to the UART,
 *          UART_ERROR on an error.
 */
extern int UART_write(UART_Handle handle, const void *buffer, size_t size);
```

sl_NetCfgGet:

```
/*!
    \brief     Internal function for getting network configurations

    \return    On success, zero is returned. On error, -1 is 
               returned

    \param[in] ConfigId      configuration id

    \param[out] pConfigOpt   Get configurations option 

    \param[out] pConfigLen   The length of the allocated memory as input, when the
                                        function complete, the value of this parameter would be
                             the len that actually read from the device.\n 
                                        If the device return length that is longer from the input 
                                        value, the function will cut the end of the returned structure
                                        and will return ESMALLBUF

    \param[out] pValues - get configurations values

    \sa         
    \note 
    \warning     
    \par



    \sample code
        SL_IPV4_AP_P2P_GO_GET_INFO:

        Get static IP address for AP or P2P go.   

        _u8 len = sizeof(SlNetCfgIpV4Args_t);
        _u8 dhcpIsOn = 0; // this flag is meaningless on AP/P2P go.
        SlNetCfgIpV4Args_t ipV4 = {0};
        sl_NetCfgGet(SL_IPV4_AP_P2P_GO_GET_INFO,&dhcpIsOn,&len,(_u8 *)&ipV4);

        printf("IP %d.%d.%d.%d MASK %d.%d.%d.%d GW %d.%d.%d.%d DNS %d.%d.%d.%d\n",                                                             
                SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4,3),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4,2),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4,1),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4,0), 
                SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4Mask,3),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4Mask,2),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4Mask,1),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4Mask,0),         
                SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4Gateway,3),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4Gateway,2),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4Gateway,1),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4Gateway,0),                 
                SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4DnsServer,3),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4DnsServer,2),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4DnsServer,1),SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4DnsServer,0));

    \endcode


*/
#if _SL_INCLUDE_FUNC(sl_NetCfgGet)
_i32 sl_NetCfgGet(_u8 ConfigId ,_u8 *pConfigOpt, _u8 *pConfigLen, _u8 *pValues);
#endif
```

Comment: and your problem in in _______ line.?   [Please tell us the problem you are facing.]

Comment: Use just *one* buffer and *one* call to `sprintf` to create the whole string in one go, then call `UART_write` only *once*?

Comment: Questions about working code belong on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Wuuzzaa: are you sure your `sprintf` works correctly? You write to array with three elements. What if integer is 3 digits long? Is there space left for null terminator (which I guess sprintf will append) in the destination array?

Comment: @Paul: I did forget to add the actual issue. See edit.

Comment: @Wuuzzaa: OK - this bug is fixed in my answer below.

Comment: @giorgim Yes, it works qiite ok. Besides the ugly spaces when there's only one digit to show.

Comment: @Wuuzzaa: it may "appear" to work, but the `sprintf` code is wrong, you have a buffer overflow there

Comment: @giorgim Thanks. I think I have to read more about sprintf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce all this:

```
   const unsigned char ip_c_3 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 3);
   char ip_3[3];
   sprintf(ip_3,"%ld", (int)ip_c_3);

   const unsigned char ip_c_2 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 2);
   char ip_2[3];
   sprintf(ip_2,"%ld", (int)ip_c_2);

   const unsigned char ip_c_1 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 1);
   char ip_1[3];
   sprintf(ip_1,"%ld", (int)ip_c_1);

   const unsigned char ip_c_0 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 0);
   char ip_0[3];
   sprintf(ip_0,"%ld", (int)ip_c_0);

   UART_write(uart,"[NETAPP EVENT] IP Acquired: ",sizeof("[NETAPP EVENT] IP Acquired: "));
   UART_write(uart,ip_3, sizeof(ip_3));
   UART_write(uart,".",1);
   UART_write(uart,ip_2,sizeof(ip_2));
   UART_write(uart,".",1);
   UART_write(uart,ip_1,sizeof(ip_1));
   UART_write(uart,".",1);
   UART_write(uart,ip_0,sizeof(ip_0));
   UART_write(uart,"\n",2);
```

to just:

```
   const char *msg = "[NETAPP EVENT] IP Acquired";
   const unsigned int ip_c_3 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 3);
   const unsigned int ip_c_2 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 2);
   const unsigned int ip_c_1 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 1);
   const unsigned int ip_c_0 = SL_IPV4_BYTE(ipV4.ipV4, 0);
   char ip[256];
   sprintf(ip, "%s: %u.%u.%u.%u\n", msg, ip_c_3, ip_c_2, ip_c_1, ip_c_0);

   UART_write(uart, ip, strlen(ip));
```

Note: this also fixes various bugs in the original code, including the problem where unwanted spaces were being introduced into the output.

Comment: :you might be using wrong format specifier in sprintf for unsigned char, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547377/format-specifier-for-unsigned-char

Comment: @giorgim: yes, strictly speaking you may be correct, but in practice I don't think it makes any difference. I'll change the types though.

Comment: Thanks you Paul! Also please add ; at the end of the first line