# Memset not zeroing char pointer

Tags: c, memset

I know there's tons of these and it's probably a simple question, but I can't seem to figure it out :(

```
char * char_buffer = (char *) malloc(64);
printf("%x\n", char_buffer);
memset(char_buffer,
       0,
       64);

printf("%x\n", char_buffer);
```

Output :

```
50000910
50000910
```

Why isn't char_buffer zero'd?  Can someone explain what's happening?

Comment: FYI: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confused about the difference between *a pointer* and *space being pointed to*.

Your code doesn't zero the pointer. It zeroes the space being pointed to. The `memset` function behaves that way.  In fact you would not want to zero the pointer, as then it would no longer point to the memory you allocated.

Your `printf` statement attempts to print the pointer's value, which is the address of the space being pointed to.  Not the contents of the space being pointed to.

Actually the printf statement causes undefined behaviour, because you mismatched format specifiers. Your compiler should have warned about this.

Here is some correct code:

```
printf("The buffer's address is %p\n", char_buffer);
printf("The buffer contains: %02X %02X %02X ...\n", 
    (unsigned char)char_buffer[0],
    (unsigned char)char_buffer[1],
    (unsigned char)char_buffer[2]);
```

To use the `%X` specifier you must pass non-negative values in, which is why the cast is necessary. You could declare the buffer as `unsigned char *` instead, in which case the cast would not be necessary.

Comment: I think you should use %d with unsigned char, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547377/format-specifier-for-unsigned-char

Comment: @Giorgi sure, if you want to print in base 10... see the answer by "mafso" explaining that it is safe to use `%d`, `%u`, or `%x`.  The C standard is unclear in defining the behaviour of these specifiers.

Comment: about the `%x` ... well, a pointer *is* convertible to an `int`, so I'd say it's not *ub* but *ib* (implementation-defined behavior). All that could happen is you get an integer overflow....

Comment: @FelixPalmen you have to actually perform a conversion yourself, e.g. `printf("%x\n", (unsigned int)p);`.  The printf function doesn't convert the arguments to match the specifiers. Imagine you are the implementor of printf, how do you know whether an argument of the correct type was given?

Comment: @M.M [I didn't implement `%p` so far](https://github.com/Zirias/clang-libdos/blob/master/src/stdio/stdio_printf.c#L92). But I see your point, if the pointer *is* larger than `int`, `printf()` will probably mess up the `va_list`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen on x64 it's common for pointers to be passed in separate registers to integers even if the same size

Comment: @M.M still `%p` isn't always satisfying as the output format isn't specified. Converting the pointer to `long` and printing that is a fairly safe workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing the **address** of the buffer, not its contents. The contents **are** zero after the `memset()`. Just try:

```
printf("%d", char_buffer[0]);
```

and see the zero ;)

Comment: You must cast the argument of `%hhu` to `(unsigned char)`

Comment: not strictly necessary, but would be cleaner. It really doesn't matter for printing zeros. And of course, you could avoid all of that using `%d`, after all, it's passed as an `int` anyways....

Comment: It is necessary because the `u` specifier expects an unsigned value but `char_buffer[0]` may be a negative value

Comment: @M.M no, not strictly. Aliasing is allowed (for several reasons, the simplest being it is a `char`). Representation of integers is guaranteed to have bits represent powers of two and to have some *sign bit* set for negative values. There's no padding bits in `char`. So a zero *is* a zero, no matter how you interpret it (except: negative zeroes, but that's not what `memset()` would write).

Comment: The printf function doesn't do aliasing, this is just undefined behaviour

Comment: no it doesn't, but it will fetch the size of an `int` from the parameters list and interpret the least significant `char` as `unsigned`. This isn't undefined.

Comment: Actually it is undefined. There's no reinterpretation. The standard says "If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined."

Comment: @M.M it's not, at least not for zero and any positive value. See e.g. 6.2.5p9

Comment: I agree that it's OK for non-negative values but it is undefined for negative values, which `char` may hold

Comment: @M.M that's correct. But here I *know* it's all zeroes :) Well, I should probably just change this to `%d` -- the conversion to `int` is "free" with a variadic function. See, I hate cast-riddled code ;) (edit: done.)

Comment: @M.M  I _think_ there is an exception to the " "If any argument is not the correct ..." such that `%x` and `int` is OK.  But its buried deep in the C standard.  I'll look later.

Comment: @chux I think the standard is badly specified. On a strict reading there is no exception, but we usually assume they meant that there is an exception otherwise it's lame.

Comment: @M.M It is in §6.5.2.2 6 Function calls: which in part "...one promoted type is a signed integer type, the other promoted type is the corresponding unsigned integer type, and the value is representable in both types ..".  These are the weasel words that allow a positive `int` to be correctly printf with `"%x"` and `unsigned` with `"%d"` if the value <= `INT_MAX`.

Comment: Some remark: The C standard always tried and still tries to describe a language as abstract and generic as possible that evolved from being just something like "assembler brought to a higher level". The technical and the abstract view might conflict sometimes. For portable code, you need the latter, but it's not easy at all ...

Comment: @chux Your quoted text is describing matching of arguments to parameters (not `...`). For example `int f(x) int x; {}` can be called with `f(0u);`

Answer (score 0):

You're printing out the pointer, not the buffer values.

`memset(p,v,n)` writes the byte `v` to the byte pointed at by `p` and `n-1` bytes after it.  It doesn't touch the pointer `p` at all (it's passed in by value, how can it?)

Answer (score 0):

To print out the buffer, you'd have to loop through it.  I use something like this:

```
void printbuf(char *buf, int size)
{
    int i = 0;
    char b = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (i % 8 == 0) {
            printf("\n%3d: ", i);
        }
        b = buf[i];
        printf("%2hhX ", b);
    }
}
```