# Is this Integer Promotion? How does it work?

Tags: c, printf, unsigned-char, integer-promotion

I was just experimenting and I tried out two printf()s.

```
unsigned char a = 1;
a = ~a;
printf("----> %x %x %x %x", ~a, a, ~a, ++a);
```

This one gave the output

```
----> ffffff00 ff ffffff00 ff
```

Next one was

```
unsigned char a = 1;
printf("----> %x %x %x %x", ~a, a, ~a, ++a);
```

This one gave the output

```
----> fffffffd 2 fffffffd 2
```

Now, I know what '++' does and '~' does. I also know that the sequence of operation inside printf is from the right.

But could some one explain the difference in the number of bytes printed? A total explanation of output would be helpful of course, but I am more interested in the number of bytes and the difference in both cases [especially in the printf a and ~a parts].

EDIT:

OK, looks like the ++ part and my mistake of "I also know that the sequence of operation inside printf is from the right" has prompted every post other than the answer I was hopefully looking for. So may be the way I asked was wrong.

I will try again,

```
unsigned char a = ~1;
a = ~a;
printf("----> %x", a);
```

OUTPUT: **----> 1**

```
unsigned char a = ~1;
printf("----> %x", ~a);
```

OUTPUT: **----> ffffff01**

Why this difference?

Comment: "I also know that the sequence of operation inside printf is from the right." - yes, that's what you're likely to see but that's not something you should generally rely on. Technically the sequence here is undefined.

Comment: " I also know that the sequence of operation inside printf is from the right." Than it is incorrect what you know.

Comment: Also `%x` expects `unsigned int` but you passed it `unsigned char`(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547377/format-specifier-for-unsigned-char)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

Comment: People should be required to read the info page of the C-tag before asking.

Comment: @hvd: It is UB by the standard. That's all to research for.

Comment: Which "number of bytes" do you mean? There is no `sizeof`.

Comment: @Olaf: take a guess.

Comment: @hvd But you do usually get predictable repeatable results for this for a given environment. OP said "from the right", i.e. right-to-left. I didn't think about it too hard but it looked correct, sorry if I got that wrong.

Comment: @Rup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior And no, the compiler might (and will) very well swap evaluatio e.g. to optimise.

Comment: @Rup: "predictable repeatable results for this for a given environment" - with UB, anything is allowed, including that. That doesn't mean that you should rely on it.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Yes! As I said in my first comment.

Comment: @Rup: too violent. just another of those questions already linked in the [C info-page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info).

Comment: You are asking two questions. Do not. Ask only one per posting.

Comment: @Olaf, My question was specifically related to difference in printf("%x", a) and printf("%x", ~a). But I think I couldnt make that clear....

P.S: People make mistakes....

Comment: @Rup Ah, thanks, I misread the question. I'm sure it's still not just technically undefined, but I don't have a concrete test case to show that and don't think it's worth it trying to come up with one. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf("----> %x %x %x %x", ~a, a, ~a, ++a);` actually invokes undefined behavior because you have a side effect on `a` and other expressions depending on the same lvalue.  So anything can happen and it is hopeless to try and explain the output produced.

Assuming 32 bit ints in 2's complement representation, if you wrote

```
printf("----> %x %x %x %x", ~a, a, ~a, a + 1);
```

You would get different and less surprising output:

```
ffffff01 fe ffffff01 ff
```

Let me explain what is going on:

```
a = ~a;
```

`a` contains `1`, is converted to an `int` with the same value, the `~` operator applied to `1` computes to `-2`, converting that back to `unsigned char` gives 254 or `0xfe`.

The arguments to `printf` are then computed as follows:

- `~a`: 0xfe is converted to `int` and all bit are complemented, yielding `0xffffff01`.
- `a` is converted to `int` with the same value and printed as `fe`.
- `~a` again of course gives the same output.
- `a+1`: `a` is converted to `int` before incrementing by one, result is 255, prints as `ff`.

> The explanation for your surprising outputs is that `a` is **first** converted to `int` and then the computation is done on the `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

`a = ~a;` You have integer promotion on this line already, since the `~`, like most operators in C, promotes the operand according to the rules of integer promotion.

The character containing value `1` gets *integer promoted* to an `int` containing the value `1`, *before* the operation is done. Assuming 32 bit `int`, the result of `~a` is a negative, two complement variable with hex value `0xFFFFFFFE`.

You then show this result back into the unsigned char, it will truncate the result and only grab the raw binary value of the least significant byte, that is: `0xFE`.

> I also know that the sequence of operation inside printf is from the right.

No. The order of evaluation of function parameters in not specified by the standard. The compiler is free to evaluate them in any order it likes, and you cannot know or assume any particular order.

Even more problematic is that there is no *sequence point* between the evaluation of the different parameters. And since in your case you are using the same variable more than once, each access to the variable is *unsequenced* and your program invokes undefined behavior. Meaning that anything can happen: weird outputs, program crashes, memory corruption etc etc.

Furthermore, `printf` is a special case, being an obscure, variadic function. All such functions have particular rules for promotion of the arguments ("the default argument promotions"). So regardless of what promotions that happen or don't happen before you pass the result to printf, printf will ruin everything by applying its own integer promotion to the parameter.

So if you wish to toy around with promotion, printf is a very bad choice for displaying the result. Try using the `sizeof` operator instead. `printf("%zu", sizeof(~a));` will for example print 4, because of integer promotion.