# Reading signed char using %u

Tags: c++, c, pointers, char, pointer-arithmetic

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i,n;
    int a = 123456789;

    void *v = &a;

    unsigned char *c = (unsigned char*)v;

    for(i=0;i< sizeof a;i++) {
        printf("%u  ",*(c+i));
    }

    char *cc = (char*)v;
    printf("\n %d", *(cc+1));

    char *ccc = (char*)v;
    printf("\n %u \n", *(ccc+1));

}
```

This program generates the following output on my 32 bit Ubuntu machine.

```
21  205  91  7  
-51
4294967245
```

First two lines of output I can understand =>

- ***1st Line*** : sequence of storing of bytes in memory.
- ***2nd Line*** : signed value of the second byte value (2's complement).
- ***3rd Line*** : why such a large value ?

please explain the last line of output. WHY three bytes of 1's are added 
because `(11111111111111111111111111001101) = 4294967245` .

Comment: because `%u` is for unsigned integer and your `*(ccc+1)` is a negative char. Unsigned integer size is longer than Char size, so there is padding. As your char is negative, there is `1` padding, as there would be `0` padding for positive char.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Apparently your compiler uses signed characters and it is a little endian, two's complement system.

```
123456789d = 075BCD15h
Little endian: 15 CD 5B 07
```

Thus v+1 gives value `0xCD`. When this is stored in a signed char, you get `-51` in signed decimal format.

When passed to printf, the character `*(ccc+1)` containing value `-51` first gets implicitly type promoted to `int`, because variadic functions like printf has a rule stating that all small integer parameters will get promoted to `int` (*the default argument promotions*). During this promotion, the sign is preserved. You still have value -51, but for a 32 bit signed integer, this gives the value `0xFFFFFFCD`.

And finally the `%u` specifier tells printf to treat this as an unsigned integer, so you end up with 4.29 bil something.

The important part to understand here is that `%u` has nothing to do with the actual type promotion, it just tells printf how to interpret the data *after* the promotion.

Comment: "The important part to understand here is that %u has nothing to do with the actual type promotion, it just tells printf how to interpret the data after the promotion." - Nice explanation :) Thanks

Comment: According to 7.21.6.1 passing an invalid type is undefined. char requires hhd and unsigned char hhu. As far as I understand the text it, the argument is the type before the promotion, because of the text in 7.21.6.1,p7: *the argument will have
been promoted according to the integer promotions* I don't think it is valid to print an unsigned char with d and rely on integer promotions. What do you think?

Comment: @2501 I think the C standard is unclear. I don't understand why fprintf should dictate some special case of undefined behavior, which would somehow overwrite the well-defined behavior of argument promotion of variable-argument list parameters. Obviously if I do something completely weird, like using `%d` while passing a float, there will be undefined behavior. Why there would be undefined behavior when mixing different, otherwise compatible integer types is less obvious.

Comment: @Lundin Well 7.21.6.1,p9 dictates ub. One might not like it but the text is there. I agree it is unclear. If after promotions we still have an argument then it is not ub.

Comment: @2501 I suppose part of the issue is that specifiers for smaller integer types must still yield well-defined behavior. For example `uint8_t x; printf("%" PRIu8, x)` is well-defined, even though technically `x` will always get promoted to `int`.  I've always thought of it as "if you use the correct format specifier, then getting the result right is no longer the responsibility of the programmer". What then happens in between the lines in forms of implicit promotions, is the compiler's problem to deal with.

Comment: @2501 [fyi](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547377/format-specifier-for-unsigned-char)

Comment: @Lundin: The problem with passing an `int` to `printf("%u")` is that varargs-functions do not convert their arguments to the type of the parameter like normal functions  (with prototypes) do. There is a special exemption for passing a `int` in place of an `unsigned` and vice versa, but *only* if the value is representable in both types.

Comment: @Lundin I think only using `hh` is correct. This is because unsigned char is not necessarily promoted to int, it could be promoted to unsigned int. So using `d` will cause ub on those architectures. This might seem ridiculous, but it is possible. Integer ranks guarantee that width of a lower rank is always a subrange, but this only holds true for the same signedness. See: 6.2.5. p8. Therefore it is possible that  `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, while also always `UCHAR_MAX <= UINT_MAX`, so unsigned char gets promoted to unsigned int.

Comment: @2501 `unsigned char` will always be promoted to `int` and never to `unsigned int`, according to the integer promotion rule, since an `int` can always represent all values of an `unsigned char`. (Unless it's some theoretical, obscure machine where `sizeof(char) == sizeof(int)`. I think we can ignore that artificial scenario.)

Comment: @Lundin You cannot ignore that if you want your code to be strictly conforming.

Comment: @2501 Sure I can. If one is worried about compatibility with theoretical, extremely weird and useless computers, simply add `_Static_assert(sizeof(char) < sizeof(int), "Your computer is too weird, why did you pick an extremely weird computer for? That's your problem, not mine. Have fun rewriting all my code.");`.

Answer (score 8):

`-51` store in 8 bit hex is `0xCD`. (Assuming 2s compliment binary  system)

When you pass it to a [variadic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function) like `printf`, default argument promotion takes place and `char` is promoted to `int` with representation `0xFFFFFFCD` (for 4 byte int).

`0xFFFFFFCD` interpreted as `int` is `-51` and interpreted as `unsigned int` is `4294967245`.

Further reading: [Default argument promotions in C function calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1255775/default-argument-promotions-in-c-function-calls)

---

> please explain the last line of output. WHY three bytes of 1's are
>   added

This is called [sign extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension). When a smaller signed number is assigned (converted) to larger number, its signed bit get's replicated to ensure it represents same number (for example in 1s and [2s compliment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)).

---

**Bad `printf` format specifier**
You are attempting to print a `char` with specifier `"%u"` which specifies `unsigned [int]`. Arguments which do not match the conversion specifier in `printf` is undefined behavior from **7.19.6.1** paragraph 9.

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is undeﬁned. If
>   any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion
>   speciﬁcation, the behavior is undeﬁned.

**Use of `char` to store signed value**
Also to ensure `char` contains `signed` value, explicitly use `signed char` as `char` may behave as `signed char` or `unsigned char`. (In latter case, output of your snippet may be `205 205`). In `gcc` you can force `char` to behave as `unsigned char` with `-funsigned-char` option.

Comment: It's debatable if it is actually undefined behavior though. Because the argument after promotion is of type `int`, not `char`. Best is of course to avoid printf family of functions entirely, since they are so prone to UB. Variadic functions should also be avoided, for the same type safety reasons.

Comment: @Lundin Thanks. This comment actually completes the answer.

Comment: The compilation is not generating any warning regarding %u. And Thanks.