# How printf() function knows the type of its arguments

Tags: c, gcc, printf

Consider the following program,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char a = 130;
    unsigned char b = 130;

    printf("a = %d\nb = %d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

This program will show the following output.

```
a = -126
b = 130
```

My question is how `printf()` function comes to know the type of `a` is signed and type of `b` is unsigned to show result like above?

Comment: @WeatherVane Totally forgot. Thanks.

Comment: char is probly valid in the range [-128, 127], hence 130 overflows. Your compiler can warn you for this kind of issues.

Comment: The `printf` function *does not know* what you pass it. It believes the format that you tell it. Only a smart compiler can pick up errors.

Comment: `char` can be `unsigned` or `signed` and its purely implementation specific, in your case though being `signed` and that's why it overflows when you print beyond `127`

Comment: `printf` doesn't know that, it believes in the format specifier `%u` or `%d`

Comment: You should be using `%u` to print `unsigned char` or cast it to `int` before passing to `printf`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya I don't think so. It will be passed as an `int` by the rules of default argument promotion anyways.

Comment: @FelixPalmen won't integer promotion take `unsigned char` to `unsigned int`? I thought integer promotions preserve signs.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya not true, 6.3.1.1 p2: "*If an int can represent all values of the original type (as restricted by the width, for a bit-field), the value is converted to an int; otherwise, it is converted to an unsigned int.*" <- `int` can represent all possible values of `unsigned char`.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya "*I thought integer promotions preserve signs*" <- sure they do, but that doesn't necessarily mean to preserve *signedness* of the type.

Comment: @FelixPalmen thanks! I wasn't aware of the clause int is given preference if the type can fit. Also, my bad on goofing up on "signs" and "signedness" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`printf()` **doesn't** know the types, that's why you have to give a correct format string. The prototype for `printf()` looks like this:

```
int printf(const char * restrict format, ...);
```

So, the only argument with a known type is the first one, the format string.

This also means that any argument passed after that is subject to *default argument promotion* -- strongly simplified, read it as any integer will be converted to *at least* `int` -- or ask google about the term to learn each and every detail ;)

In your example, you have *implementation defined behavior*:

```
char a = 130;
```

If your `char` could represent `130`, that's what you would see in the output of `printf()`. Promoting the value to `int` doesn't change the value. You're getting a negative number instead, which means `130` overflowed your `char`. The result of overflowing a **signed** integer type during conversion in C is **implementation defined**, the value you're getting probably means that on you machine, `char` has 8 bits (so the maximum value is `127`) and the signed integer overflow resulted in a *wraparound* to the negative value range. You can't rely on that behavior!

In short, the negative number is created in this line -- `130` is of type `int`, assigning it to `char` converts it and this conversion overflows.

Once your `char` has the value `-126`, passing it to `printf()` just converts it to `int`, not changing the value.

Answer (score 2):

The additional arguments to `printf()` are formatted according to the type specifier. See here for a list of C format specifiers.

https://fr.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf

It's true that one would not expect `b` to be printed as `130` in your example since you used the `%d` specifier and not `%u`. This surprising behavior seems to be explained here.

[Format specifier for unsigned char](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27547377/format-specifier-for-unsigned-char)

I hope I got your question well.

Edit: I can not comment Felix Palmen's answer on account on my low reputation.  *default argument promotion* indeed seems to be the key here, but to me the real question here besides the overflow of `a` is why `b` is still printed as `130` despite the use of the signed specifier. It can also be explained with *default argument promotion* but that should be made more precise.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` does not know the data type of arguments. It works on format specifier you passed. The data type you are using is `char` (having range from -128 to +127) and `unsigned char` (having range from 0 to 255). Your output for `a` is overflowed after 127. So the output comes to -126.

Comment: char has 8 bit size. How 130 cause overflow in 8 bits

Comment: @AjithcNarayanan `char` doesn't **have** to have 8 bits, but it's very common. You forgot the need for a *sign bit* in a signed type. See my answer for some more explanation.

Comment: Storing 130 in a char will set sign bit but it doesn’t cause any overflow and complier doesn’t show any warnings. Please check it

Comment: @AjithcNarayanan try `-Wconversion` if you use gcc. overflow isn't the wording of the standard for such a conversion, but something implementation-defined **does** happen because `130` can't be represented in an (8bit) `signed char`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a look at the definition of `printf` statement in `stdio.h`. You already got the answer in comment `printf` just write the string pointed by format to stdout.

It's variadic function and it use vargas to get all the arguments in variable-length argument list.

You
This is from the [glibc from the GNU version](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=stdio-common/printf.c;h=4c8f3a2a0c38ab27a2eed4d2ff3b804980aa8f9f;hb=3321010338384ecdc6633a8b032bb0ed6aa9b19a).

```
int __printf (const char *format, ...)
{
   va_list arg;
   int done;

   va_start (arg, format);
   done = vfprintf (stdout, format, arg);
   va_end (arg);

   return done;
}
```

**What vfprintf does?**

It just writes the string pointed by format to the stream, replacing any format specifier in the same way as printf does, but using the elements in the variable argument list identified by arg instead of additional function arguments.

More information about the [vfprintf](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/3-vfprintf/)