# Is there way to get the last byte of data of off a short and save it into a char

Tags: c

I'm following a tutorial to write an emulator for the Chip8.
Opcodes are 2 bytes long and in HEX. They are stored in unsigned short data types (which is 2 bytes).

I want to get the last byte off of one of these shorts and save it on a char (1 byte).

I have tried using the & operation to filter out the first byte and then assign to a char variable.

```cpp
unsigned short opcode = 0x56FA; //sample opcode
char mychar = opcode & 0x00FF;  //& operation to make 1st byte zeros
printf("%02X \n", mychar);      //should print last byte FA
```

I expect for it to print FA.
but instead prints out FFFFFFFA.

Comment: Use `unsigned char`. When you are using `char` the value is negative.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to do it even skipping the & operation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `printf("%02X \n", mychar);` `mychar` is promoted to an integer and that integer is then printed. In your case `mychar` is signed and is in fact negative, so the value is promoted to a negative integer and you are getting the output `FFFFFFFA`. If instead you use `unsigned char` then you will get the expected output.

Your question seems like a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3555791/why-does-printf-not-print-out-just-one-byte-when-printing-hex) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3555936/8767209) is better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast to a char to truncate the short into a char. Casting converts the binary value into the correct length.

short = 5; --> 0000 0000 0000 0101 
When casting it becomes --> 0000 0101
Truncating the short to a char.

```
unsigned char opcode = (char)(opcode & 0x00ff)
```